# How to do email validation by blocking some email domain names in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, validation, email, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I need to validate an email field in gravity form. We have some known list of email domains and need to validate whether that domains present or not and If that domains present means we need to show the error message.

What is the best way to implement that? Any plugin suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with the GW_Email_Domain_Validator snippet here:

https://gravitywiz.com/banlimit-email-domains-for-gravity-form-email-fields/

Full snippet as of July 18, 2020 included here. Use the link above to get the latest version.

```
<?php
/**
 * Gravity Wiz // Gravity Forms // Email Domain Validator
 *
 * This snippets allows you to exclude a list of invalid domains or include a list of valid domains for your Gravity Form Email fields.
 *
 * @version   1.4
 * @author    David Smith <david@gravitywiz.com>
 * @license   GPL-2.0+
 * @link      http://gravitywiz.com/banlimit-email-domains-for-gravity-form-email-fields/
 */

class GW_Email_Domain_Validator {

    private $_args;

    function __construct($args) {

        $this->_args = wp_parse_args( $args, array(
            'form_id' => false,
            'field_id' => false,
            'domains' => false,
            'validation_message' => __( 'Sorry, <strong>%s</strong> email accounts are not eligible for this form.' ),
            'mode' => 'ban' // also accepts "limit"
        ) );

        // convert field ID to an array for consistency, it can be passed as an array or a single ID
        if($this->_args['field_id'] && !is_array($this->_args['field_id']))
            $this->_args['field_id'] = array($this->_args['field_id']);

        $form_filter = $this->_args['form_id'] ? "_{$this->_args['form_id']}" : '';

        add_filter("gform_validation{$form_filter}", array($this, 'validate'));

    }

    function validate($validation_result) {

        $form = $validation_result['form'];

        foreach($form['fields'] as &$field) {

            // if this is not an email field, skip
            if(RGFormsModel::get_input_type($field) != 'email')
                continue;

            // if field ID was passed and current field is not in that array, skip
            if($this->_args['field_id'] && !in_array($field['id'], $this->_args['field_id']))
                continue;

            $page_number = GFFormDisplay::get_source_page( $form['id'] );
            if( $page_number > 0 && $field->pageNumber != $page_number ) {
                continue;
            }

            if( GFFormsModel::is_field_hidden( $form, $field, array() ) ) {
                continue;
            }

            $domain = $this->get_email_domain($field);

            // if domain is valid OR if the email field is empty, skip
            if($this->is_domain_valid($domain) || empty($domain))
                continue;

            $validation_result['is_valid'] = false;
            $field['failed_validation'] = true;
            $field['validation_message'] = sprintf($this->_args['validation_message'], $domain);

        }

        $validation_result['form'] = $form;
        return $validation_result;
    }

    function get_email_domain( $field ) {
        $email = explode( '@', rgpost( "input_{$field['id']}" ) );
        return trim( rgar( $email, 1 ) );
    }

    function is_domain_valid( $domain ) {

        $mode   = $this->_args['mode'];
        $domain = strtolower( $domain );

        foreach( $this->_args['domains'] as $_domain ) {

            $_domain = strtolower( $_domain );

            $full_match   = $domain == $_domain;
            $suffix_match = strpos( $_domain, '.' ) === 0 && $this->str_ends_with( $domain, $_domain );
            $has_match    = $full_match || $suffix_match;

            if( $mode == 'ban' && $has_match ) {
                return false;
            } else if( $mode == 'limit' && $has_match ) {
                return true;
            }

        }

        return $mode == 'limit' ? false : true;
    }

    function str_ends_with( $string, $text ) {

        $length      = strlen( $string );
        $text_length = strlen( $text );

        if( $text_length > $length ) {
            return false;
        }

        return substr_compare( $string, $text, $length - $text_length, $text_length ) === 0;
    }

}
```

To only accept submissions from a given email domain you can do something like this:

```php
new GW_Email_Domain_Validator( array(
    'form_id' => 326,
    'field_id' => 1,
    'domains' => array( 'gmail.com', 'hotmail.com', '.co.uk' ),
    'validation_message' => __( 'Oh no! <strong>%s</strong> email accounts are not eligible for this form.' ),
    'mode' => 'limit'
) );
```

Comment: Hey Dave, your answer may become unuseful in the future if your website ever goes down. That's why Stack Overflow encourages users to include everything needed in the answer itself, linking to external pages is generally not well regarded here. See here for more details: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259. (I'm telling you all this so you understand why I edited your answer.)

Comment: Appreciate your clarification, cabrerahector. I've left the inclusion of the snippet and re-added the link to the snippet article. It provides a considerable amount of additional value to the user and keeps the answer fresh by allowing other folks reading this answer in the future to get the latest version of the snippet.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Where we have to insert this code in this WordPress?

Comment: Easiest way is to add it to your theme's functions.php file.